# Intuition about relative homotopy $\Pi_1(X, A, x_0)$ and coset

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm studying Algebraic Topology, and I want to get some intuition about relative homology.
In Hatcher's book, there is some remark that

> For a pair $(X,A)$ of path-connected spaces, $\Pi_1(X, A, x_0)$ can be identified in the natural way with the set of cosets of $\alpha H$ that $H$ is loop in $A$ at $x_0$.

But, I cannot catch any pictorial or good reason why this holds. I think the situation that $[f] = [g]$ in $\Pi_1(X, A, x_0)$, but I cannot find any reason that $[f]$ and $[g]$ are in the same coset. Can you give me some intuition? I know this is easy question, but I really want to understand intuitively high homotopy class. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the correct statement of the exercise (Hatcher, section 4.1, exercise 5) is:

> For a pair $(X,A)$ of path-connected spaces, show that $\pi_1(X, A, x_0)$ can be identified in a natural way with the set of cosets $\alpha H$ of the **subgroup** $H \subset \pi_1(X,x_0)$ represented by loops in $A$ at $x_0$.

Since you are only asking for intuition, let me sketch the map in one direction and leave the details for you to check.  By definition an element in $\pi_1(X,A,x_0)$ is represented by a path in $X$ that starts at $x_0$ and ends somewhere in $A$.  We can try to define a map from $\pi_1(X,A,x_0)$ to $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ as follows: for each point $a \in A$, fix a path $\gamma_a$ in $A$ connecting $a$ with $x_0$, which is possible since $A$ is path-connected.  Then, given a path $f$ in $X$ that starts at $x_0$ and ends at $a \in A$, we can concatenate with the path $\gamma_a$ from $a$ to $x_0$ to get a loop $f \cdot \gamma_a$ in $X$ that starts and ends at $x_0$, which represents an element in $\pi_1(X,x_0)$.

However, this map $\pi_1(X,A,x_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_0)$ is not well-defined!  The choice of path connecting $a$ with $x_0$ matters.  Given two different choices of path $\gamma_a$ and $\gamma_a'$, the concatenated paths $f \cdot \gamma_a$ and $f \cdot \gamma_a'$ differ by $\overline{\gamma_a} \cdot \gamma_a'$, which is a loop in $A$.  So incorporating this ambiguity, what we actually get is not an element of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ but a coset of the subgroup of loops in $A$ based at $x_0$.

You should check that making this change gives a well-defined bijection between $\pi_1(X,A,x_0)$ and the set of cosets defined in the exercise.

Comment: How do you show surjectivity of this bijection? I have defined a well defined map $\phi\colon \mathrm{Im}i_*\setminus\pi_1(X,x_0)\to\pi_1(X,A,x_0)$ by $\phi(\mathrm{Im}i_* + [f]):= j_*[f]$, where $i\colon(A,x_0)\to(X,x_0)$ and $j\colon(X,x_0,x_0)\to(X,A,x_0)$ denote the usual inclusions. To show surjectivity it seems to boil down to: if $[f] = [g] \in\pi_1(X,A,x_0)$ then $f+\overline{g}$ is homotopic to a loop in $A$, where $\overline{g}$ denotes the inverse path to $g$. I explicitly am in search for such a homotopy! Do you have any suggestions?